# Spring Cloud Gateway Service Discover Locator

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway, service-discovery

i'm fetching some services that are registered in Eureka server using Service discover locator. by default service discover locator add one filter and one predicate to the routes that it creates from services fetch from Eureka. i want to update these routes and make some changes on them. for that i'm using this code:
i have injected this class DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator discoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator;
and do the following you see in the code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RouteDefinitionUpdater implements CommandLineRunner {
 DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator discoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator;

 @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
 discoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator.getRouteDefinitions().map(this::updateRouteDefinition).subscribe();
}

private RouteDefinition updateRouteDefinition(RouteDefinition routeDefinition) {
        log.info(" updateRouteDefinition executed for {}", routeDefinition.getId());
        URI uri = URI.create("https://test.com");
        routeDefinition.setUri(uri);
        return routeDefinition;
    }

}
```

the code run without any problem , but the problem is that after run method i check discoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator.getRouteDefinitions() i see that my changes are not applied and the URI in the routes is the one fetch from Eureka.

does anybody know what i'm doing wrong here ?

i searched a lot about this and i know there is manual way of changing properties of the routes that service discovery locator is creating using application.yml, but i want do the changes inside my code.